# Usage of the ref function in ML

Tags: sml, ml

Considering the ref operator I'm having trouble to understand its application and the sense of the follow instructions:

**1.**

In this definition what am I defining?

```
 - val ref x=ref 9;

 val x = 9 : int
```

**2.**

and here what am I doing with ref x:= ref 12?

```
 - val x= ref 8;

 val x = ref 8 : int ref

 - ref x := ref 12; 

 val it = () : unit

 - x;

 val it = ref 8 : int ref
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`val ref x = ref 9` defines `x` to be `9` - just as if you had written `val x = 9`. This is because `ref` is a constructor, so it's pattern matching the value `ref 9` against the pattern `ref x`, which binds `x` to 9. Of course writing it like this instead of just writing `val x = 9` makes very little sense.

When you write `ref x := ref 12`, you create a new `ref` (of type `int ref ref`) that refers to `x`. You then immediately change that new `ref` to refer to `ref 12` rather than to `x`. Since the new `ref` you created is never stored anywhere where you might access, this will have no observable effect.

Comment: it's interesting that `ref` can be unpacked in pattern matching in SML. "`ref` is a constructor" doesn't seem to be documented anywhere

Comment: @newacct To be honest, I'm not entirely sure whether this is standard behaviour or implementation specific (and I don't have the standard handy to check).

Answer (score 0):

@newacct, @sepp2k I see this is from several years ago, but I found the discussion useful and wanted to contribute this output from `Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Tue Aug  8 16:57:33 2017]`:

```
- val ref x = ref 9;
val x = 9 : int
```