# Can we get the reference denoted by a variable in SML?

Tags: programming-languages, sml, ml

in SML, consider side effect by references.

- Is it correct that any variable (whether used with or without side effect) denotes a reference which then refers to a value?
- is it possible to get the reference denoted by a variable? Is there an operation like `&` in C for the same purpose? (In SML, a variable as an expression is by default evaluated not to the reference denoted by the variable, but to the value referred to by the reference denoted by the variable.)
- Can an reference be the result from evaluating an expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your first question isn't completely clear. Not all values in SML are `ref` types. In `val a = 3`, the name `a` is bound to an `int` rather than an `int ref` type. So in that sense the answer is simply "no", not all values in SML are references, most of them are not. On the other hand, it is a bit on an implementation question if under the hood an SML implementation uses references to manage the bindings of names to values.

For your other two questions, given any type `'a` in SML there is a related reference type `'a ref`. You can create values of this type and assign them to variables. Given a value of a `ref` type you can dereference it (using the operator `!`) to get to the value it refers to (otherwise it would be somewhat useless) and you can return reference types from functions. In fact the function `ref` is a polymorphic function which return reference types. See [sml - Usage of the ref function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16134306/4996248).

SML doesn't have an address operator like `&` in C, but reference types can be made to refer to the value to which a name is bound.

Given

```
val a = 4
val b = ref(3)
```

b is now an `int ref`. That `b` can be made to refer to the value that `a` is bound to:

```
b := a
```

Now `!b` evaluates to `4`. So in that sense `:=` is similar to `= &` in C, but it is an implementation detail if under the hood `b` was made to point to the same memory location that the value of `a` was stored in or if the value was copied to the place where `b` was already pointing.

Comment: Thanks. My second question is: is it possible to get the reference denoted by a variable? Is there an operation like & in C for the same purpose?

Comment: @Tim I edited the question. I think that perhaps you were wondering what corresponds to `p = &x;` in C. The closest match is `p := x`, but that doesn't mean that the semantics are exactly the same,